# Excel Listbox listindex does not highlight

Tags: excel, listboxitems, vba

Could someone with a better level of excel capability please assist me with the below code?  I have set this up in the Worksheet_Activate event.  I have code to set an ActiveX listbox to a default value, as shown below.  For whatever reason, the listbox is not showing the default value as a highlighted item.  All the other logic seems to work fine but it's driving me crazy that the below code won't highlight the stupid first item in my first listbox.  What am I doing wrong?

```
With CTOverview.ListBox1
    .IntegralHeight = True
    .Height = 114.75
    .Width = 125.25
    .IntegralHeight = False
    .ListIndex = 0
    .Selected(0) = True
    .Value = "Entire Division"
End With

CTData.Range("Overview_RegionSelected").Value = CTOverview.ListBox1.Value

With CTOverview.ListBox2
    .IntegralHeight = True
    .Height = 114.75
    .Width = 150
    .IntegralHeight = False
    .ListIndex = -1
End With
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know. I have seen this weird behavior in the past with absolutely no explanation. Sometime it works and sometimes it doesn't. Try this. This will work.

```
With CTOverview.ListBox1
    If .ListCount > 1 Then .Selected(1) = True
    .IntegralHeight = True
    .Height = 114.75
    .Width = 125.25
    .IntegralHeight = False
    .ListIndex = 0
    .Selected(0) = True
    .Value = "Entire Division"
End With
```

**FOLLOWUP**

Here is a better code than the code that I gave you earlier. The above code was restricted to the fact that we needed to have **more** than 1 `Listcount`. The below will work for 1 `Listcount` as well.

```
Dim rng As Range, aCell As Range

With CTOverview.ListBox1
    .IntegralHeight = True
    .Height = 114.75
    .Width = 125.25
    .IntegralHeight = False
    .ListIndex = 0
    .Selected(0) = True
    .Value = "Entire Division"

    Set rng = Range(.ListFillRange)
    For Each aCell In rng
        aCell.Formula = aCell.Formula
    Next
End With
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion.  I added the line to my code and it does work.  However, do I have to use

Comment: Seems like you didn't finish your sentence in the above comment?

Comment: So sorry - I attempted to edit it and that didn't work too well.  :-)

Comment: Do you have any idea why this happens?

Comment: Honestly I have no idea why does this happen. And I am not sure if it is a bug. Anyways I have updated my answer. See the FOLLOWUP section. You might have to refresh the page.

Comment: Since you have accepted the answer, I am guessing that the 2nd one did help you :P

Answer (score 2):

Setting .Selected to False and immediately setting it to True worked for me:

```
With Me.Charts_LB
    .ColumnHeads = False
    .RowSource = rng.Address
    .Height = 480
    .Selected(Charts_ListIndex) = False
    .Selected(Charts_ListIndex) = True
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplify your code. Either use the `.Selected` property or the `.ListIndex` property or the `.Value` property to have an item in the list selected.

In your first listbox (ListBox1), you have used all the three properties to have your default selection in effect. Probably you are having inconsistent values in your code like the first item of the list not being "Entire Division". If your first item is "Entire Division" only, then have any one of the properties in place to effect your desired selection.

In the second listbox (ListBox2), when your code has `.ListIndex` = -1, it means that you want to deselect everything. So change the desired list index to 0 to have the first item selected.

Given that you want the first options of the list boxes selected by default, have the following as a base.

```
With CTOverview.ListBox1
    .ListIndex = 0
End With

With CTOverview.ListBox2
    .ListIndex = 0
End With
```

Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: I did actually start with just .ListIndex = 0 but then I started adding the other stuff to try to figure out why the damn thing wouldn't work.  And I don't want Listbox2 to select anything so that code is ok as is.  Your first suggestion works well but it looks a bit odd - the 2nd item is highlighted and then the first item is selected.  Annoying MS bugs.

Comment: @user2296377 This happens when the .listindex = 0 is followed by the .value = <Second Value>. MS does exactly what we code in!

Answer (score 0):

So I had the same problem and I referred the Office documentation and realized  that everything depended on the premise that the listbox should be in focus to have its value attribute to return value.

I propose that you simply add a line at the end to bring focus.

```
With CTOverview.ListBox1
    .IntegralHeight = True
    .Height = 114.75
    .Width = 125.25
    .IntegralHeight = False
    .ListIndex = 0
    .Selected(0) = True
    .Value = "Entire Division"
    .SetFocus
End With
```

Comment: You may not need .Value line to explicitly set value.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a similar problem with ListBox controls in UserForms (not ActiveX controls embedded in a worksheet), but since I haven't found any other postings that show up on the first couple of Google search pages, I'm attaching my solution to this one, since it is likely that people hunting for UserForm solutions will hit on this post, plus it may also be helpful to some who are using straight ActiveX ListBox controls.

In UserForms (at least) setting .ListIndex = n and .Selected(n) = True doesn't seem to help at all.  The only workaround that I've found is this, where "n" is the list item to be selected/highlighted:

```
Dim SaveVal As String
With MyUserForm.SomeListBox
    SaveVal = .List(n)
    .Value = ""
    .Value = SaveVal
    .SetFocus   'Not required, but allows up/down arrow keys to function normally.
End With
```

Note that just re-assigning the selected list item to its current value doesn't work because the underlying code apparently checks for that case and treats it as a no-op.